# Calculate sum of value in python list based of employee name field

Tags: python

Greeting everyone, I have a list in my python file, based from this list how can I calculate sum of the `actual_duration` for each of the employee A, B and C?

Below is my list :

```
[{'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 14}, 
{'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 6}, 
{'employee_name': 'B', 'actual_duration': 8}, 
{'employee_name': 'B', 'actual_duration': 22}, 
{'employee_name': 'C', 'actual_duration': 15}]
```

Comment: Hello, when you propose a current status and a desired result, it is as if you are asking the Stack Overflow community to simply do your work for you -- which I'm sure is not what you want, and it is not the purpose of Stack Overflow. A better way to ask a question like this would be to show what you have tried, any erroneous output or error messages you're getting, research the issue, share your research and ask about what part you don't understand, that way we can help you yet you still are the author of your code.

Comment: Simple: show your code.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this is a small chunk of code I pull out from a huge project as it is confidential, I tried for days now, and I'm desperate for help, I've tried and it getting the sum of everything instead hence I'm asking it here

Comment: Hint: from collections import Counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using `collections.defaultdict`

```
l = [   {'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 14}, 
        {'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 6}, 
        {'employee_name': 'B', 'actual_duration': 8}, 
        {'employee_name': 'B', 'actual_duration': 22}, 
        {'employee_name': 'C', 'actual_duration': 15}  ]

from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(int)

for k,v in [d.values() for d in l]:
    d_dict[k]+=v

new_l = []
for k,v in d_dict.items():
    new_l.append({'employee_name': k, 'actual_duration': v})

new_l
```

Output:

```
[{'actual_duration': 20, 'employee_name': 'A'},
 {'actual_duration': 30, 'employee_name': 'B'},
 {'actual_duration': 15, 'employee_name': 'C'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, using a `for` loop to iterate over the original list and concatenate items:

```
for entry in times:
    if entry['employee_name'] not in map(lambda i: i['employee_name'], aggregate):
            aggregate.append(entry)
    else:
            aggregate[map(lambda i: i['employee_name'], aggregate).index(entry['employee_name'])]['actual_duration']+=entry['actual_duration']
```

---

```
>>> times = [{'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 14}, 
... {'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 6}, 
... {'employee_name': 'B', 'actual_duration': 8}, 
... {'employee_name': 'B', 'actual_duration': 22}, 
... {'employee_name': 'C', 'actual_duration': 15}]
>>> aggregate = []
>>> for entry in times:
...     if entry['employee_name'] not in map(lambda i: i['employee_name'], aggregate):
...             aggregate.append(entry)
...     else:
...             print map(lambda i: i['employee_name'], aggregate).index(entry['employee_name'])
...             aggregate[map(lambda i: i['employee_name'], aggregate).index(entry['employee_name'])]['actual_duration']+=entry['actual_duration']
... 
0
1
>>> aggregate
[{'actual_duration': 20, 'employee_name': 'A'}, {'actual_duration': 30, 'employee_name': 'B'}, {'actual_duration': 15, 'employee_name': 'C'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approach , one is using default dict:

```
your_data=[{'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 14},
{'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 6},
{'employee_name': 'B', 'actual_duration': 8},
{'employee_name': 'B', 'actual_duration': 22},
{'employee_name': 'C', 'actual_duration': 15}]


from collections import defaultdict

default_dict=defaultdict(list)

for i in your_data:
    track=[]
    for j,l in i.items():
        [track.insert(0, (l, j)) if isinstance(l,int) else track.insert(1,(l,j))]





    default_dict[track[1]].append(track[0][0])

print({'employee_name : {}'.format(key[0]):'actual_duration : {} '.format(sum(values)) for key,values in default_dict.items()})
```

output:

```
{'employee_name : A': 'actual_duration : 20 ', 'employee_name : C': 'actual_duration : 15 ', 'employee_name : B': 'actual_duration : 30 '}
```

> Second detailed solution without using default_dict:

```
new={}
for i in your_data:
    track=[]
    for j,l in i.items():
        [track.insert(0, (l, j)) if isinstance(l,int) else track.insert(1,(l,j))]


    if track[1] not in new:
        new[track[1]]=[track[0][0]]
    else:
        new[track[1]].append(track[0][0])








print({'employee_name : {}'.format(key[0]):'actual_duration : {} '.format(sum(values)) for key,values in new.items()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 14}, 
{'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 6}, 
{'employee_name': 'B', 'actual_duration': 8}, 
{'employee_name': 'B', 'actual_duration': 22}, 
{'employee_name': 'C', 'actual_duration': 15}]

result = pd.DataFrame(data).groupby('employee_name').sum()
print(result)

               actual_duration
employee_name                 
A                           20
B                           30
C                           15
```

If you want a dict back you can do

```
result_dict = result.reset_index().to_dict('records')
print(result_dict)

[{'actual_duration': 20, 'employee_name': 'A'},
 {'actual_duration': 30, 'employee_name': 'B'},
 {'actual_duration': 15, 'employee_name': 'C'}]
```